# The logic behind implementation of ord() in Lutz's "Learning Python "

Tags: python, ascii, ord

I can't wrap my head around the example implementation of ord() function given in this book:

```
>>> B = '1101' # Convert binary digits to integer with ord
>>> I = 0
>>> while B != '':
... I = I * 2 + (ord(B[0]) - ord('0'))
... B = B[1:]
...
>>> I
13
```

Particurlarly I can't understand what are we achieving with this calculation 'I = I * 2 + (ord(B[0]) - ord('0'))'? Can anybody please explain step by step what this program does?

Comment: This isn't "implementation" of `ord`; it's *using* `ord`. As for what it does, did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial resource; "explain this code to me" is not an appropriate request.  Trace the code yourself; if there's a particular step that confuses you, post the details of what you don't understand.

Comment: I know what ord does, it returns ascii code point of a character, I just can't understand where this calculation came from? why do we need to start with 0, and then for some reason mupltiply it by 2 and add to it the difference between 0 and 0 or 1 and 0? I've traced the code, calculations are fine, those I can do, but it just doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(ord(B[0]) - ord('0'))` is a very cumbersome way of doing `int(B[0])`.

The `ord` function returns the numeric value of the Unicode codepoint for a single character string. For digits and characters from the Latin alphabet, that's the ASCII value, somewhere between 0 and 127. For more exotic characters (like accented vowels, or Chinese characters), you'll get a larger number. A feature of the ASCII character set is the the numeric characters are arranged in order. Zero is character 48, one is character 49 and so on. That means you can do math on the `ord` values and it may correspond to doing math on the numbers themselves. If you subtract `ord('0')` from the `ord` of some other digit character, you'll get that other character's value.

But Python has better ways to do that, most of the time. It's a whole lot clearer if you convert a string into an integer with `int`, rather than using math with `ord`. I have no idea why the book you're reading would suggest doing it that way, unless learning about `ord` was the point of the exercise. And actually there's a lot of weird stuff in that code example. Using a `for` loop is a much more natural way to iterate over the characters of a string, rather than using slicing and a while loop, while constantly looking up the string's first character.

If I couldn't use `int(some_string, 2)` to covert a binary string to a number, I'd write:

```
def convert_binary_to_int(bin_str):
    val = 0
    for char in bin_str:
        val *= 2
        val += int(char) # or maybe use char == '1', if you can't call int at all
    return val
```

As I commented in the code, if you can't use `int` at all, an alternative for converting each binary digit might be `char == '1'`, which will be `True` or `False`. Those values are equal to `1` and `0`, respectively, which is in fact the numerical value you want!

Comment: This looks kind of like someone tried to convert some C code into Python as directly as possible. The `B = B[1:]` is a poor analogue of incrementing a `char *`, the `ord` and subtraction looks like a translation of `some_char - '0'`, and the `while` is like stopping at the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured out the answer to my question. I couldn't understand the math behind this code, why we need to start with 0 and then multiply by 2, etc. Turns out it's just the reverse of repeating division-by-2 method. E.g 13 is 1101 in binary, and one way of converting it is below

```
    13|2  rem 1
    6 |2  rem 0
    3 |2  rem 1
    1 |2  rem 1
    0
```

Now we just have to start from the bottom, that means

```
    0 * 2 + rem 1 = 1
    1 * 2 + rem 1 = 3
    3 * 2 + rem 0 = 6
    6 * 2 + rem 1 = 13
```

Guess I have probably worded my question incorrectly.